# rancher LDAP authentication failed if username contain dot

Tags: active-directory, ldap, rancher

I installed rnacher version 2.7.6 with helm in my kubernetes cluster and i use Active Directory ldap to authentication of my users. rancher join AD successfully but users that have dot in middle of username con not authenticate.

I tried to change attributes, username configuration in AD and bind dn and search dn. but the problem not solved.[image]